# How to gsub on the text between two words in R?

Tags: regex, r, gsub

***EDIT:***

I would like to place a `\n` before a specific unknown word in my text. I know that the first time the unknown word appears in my text will be between "Tree" and "Lake"

Ex. of text:

```
text
[1]  "TreeRULakeSunWater" 
[2]  "A B C D"
```

***EDIT:***

"Tree" and "Lake" will never change, but the word in between them is always changing so I do not look for "RU" in my `regex`

What I am currently doing:

```
if (grepl(".*Tree\\s*|Lake.*",  text)) { text <- gsub(".*Tree\\s*|Lake.*", "\n\\1", text)}
```

The problem with what I am doing above is that the `gsub` will sub all of `text` and leave just `\nRU`.

```
text
[1] "\nRU"
```

I have also tried:

```
if (grepl(".*Tree *(.*?) *Lake.*",  text)) { text <- gsub(".*Tree *(.*?) *Lake.*", "\n\\1", text)}
```

What I would like `text` to look like after `gsub`:

```
text
[1] "Tree \nRU LakeSunWater"
[2] "A B C D"
```

***EDIT:***

From Wiktor Stribizew's comment I am able to do a successful `gsub`

```
gsub("Tree(\\w+)Lake", "Tree \n\\1 Lake", text)
```

But this will only do a gsub on occurrences where "RU" is between "Tree and "Lake", which is the first occurrence of the unknown word. The unknown word and in this case "RU" will show up many times in the text, and I would like to place `\n` in front of every occurrence of "RU" when "RU" is a whole word.

New Ex. of text.

```
text
[1] "TreeRULakeSunWater"
[2] "A B C RU D"
```

New Ex. of what I would like:

```
text
[1] "Tree \nRU LakeSunWater"
[2] "A B C \nRU D"
```

Any help will be appreciated. Please let me know if further information is needed.

Comment: [`gsub("Tree(\\w+)Lake", "Tree \n\\1 Lake", text)`](https://ideone.com/ysFaiG)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have edited my question

Comment: How could you specify how `RU` can be identified in the text? 2 consecutive uppercase letters? Try [`gsub("[[:space:]]*([[:upper:]]{2})[[:space:]]*", " \n\\1 ", text)`](https://ideone.com/qvXAZu).

Comment: The two words surrounding it always be the same. "Tree" and "Lake".

Comment: In that case, the last example `RU` is not surrounded by 'Tree' and 'Lake'

Comment: @akrun I have edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: I hope I understood what you need. Please check my answer.

Comment: @Dre I think I will delete my answer if you are changing it many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *find* the unknown word between "Tree" and "Lake" first. You can use

```
unknown_word <- gsub(".*Tree(\\w+)Lake.*", "\\1", text)
```

The pattern matches any characters up to the last `Tree` in a string, then captures the unknown word (`\w+` = one or more word characters) up to the `Lake` and then matches the rest of the string. It replaces all the strings in the vector. You can access the first one by `[[1]]` index.

Then, when you know the word, replace it with

```
gsub(paste0("[[:space:]]*(", unknown_word[[1]], ")[[:space:]]*"), " \n\\1 ", text)
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/qvXAZu).

Here, you have `[[:space:]]*(` + unknown_word[[1](https://ideone.com/qvXAZu)] + `)[[:space:]]*` pattern. It matches zero or more whitespaces on both ends of the unknown word, and the unknown word itself (captured into Group 1). In the replacement, the spaces are shrunk into 1 (or added if there were none) and then `\\1` restores the unknown word. You may replace `[[:space:]]` with `\\s`.

**UPDATE**

If you need to only add a newline symbols before `RU` that are whole words, use the `\b` word boundary:

```
> gsub(paste0("[[:space:]]*\\b(", unknown_word[[1]], ")\\b[[:space:]]*"), " \n\\1 ", text)
[1] "TreeRULakeSunWater" "A B C \nRU D"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it worked perfectly, but I do have a follow up. In my text the unknown word and in this case "RU" appears in the middle of many other words. Once I have matched the unknown word I would only like to put `\n` in front of "RU" when it is a whole word. I will edit my question again. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Does it mean you need to achieve `[1] "TreeRULakeSunWater" "A B C \nRU D"`? I added this scenario to the answer. Please avoid changing the question so many times, it is frowned upon on SO.

Comment: Yes, that would be acceptable. The first occurrence does not need a `\n` but it can. The subsequent "RU"s do need a `\n` in front of it.

Comment: Would you suggest that I delete this question and ask a new one?

Comment: Why deleting it? I  just warn you so that your future questions do not get downvoted.